# How to remove old A/C piping in my house?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, copper, copper-tubing

When I had my new A/C installed I moved it to the other side of my house (right next to the furnace), so now I have a bunch of old copper piping running about 30 feet from one corner of my house to the other.

My question - is this trivial to remove? Do I just need pipe cutters or is there a better way to do it?  Here is a photo:

[image]

I mainly want to do this as my basement is small and there are quite large drop ceilings ONLY because of this pipe, I want to remove the drop ceiling entirely. See here:

[image]

And are there any risks? I assume nothing is in either pipe and I could just cut/remove them.

Answer (score 1):

If the refrigerant has been removed, this is an easy task.  I'd assume the refrigerant was recovered when the old condensing unit was removed, but I only know what you've told us.

If there's no refrigerant in the lines, simply cut them out any way you like. Take the copper to the local scrap yard, and you can pay yourself for the work.

If the refrigerant is still in the lines, you'll have to have it recovered by an HVAC technician.

Comment: I suspect it is removed, but i could open one end and look. Do I just use pipe cutters? Or a hack saw? Or a reciprocating saw?